# Google Sheet `MailApp.sendEmail`: how to create multi-line message body?

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a simple answer. I have created a script to send an email through Google Sheet Script Editor:

```
function mailtest() { MailApp.sendEmail("name.surname@etteachers.com", 
                                        "Availability Change", 
                                        "Hi Please note that...."); }
```

The body of the email however keeps all the text in one row starting at the top of the email body. How do I get the part "Please note that" two rows below "Hi" in the email?

Comment: Please include the script.

Comment: function mailtest() {
MailApp.sendEmail("name.surname@etteachers.com", "Availability Change", "Hi Please note that....");
}

Answer (score 0):

Add two new lines to your message like this:

```
function mailtest() { 
    MailApp.sendEmail(""name.surname@etteachers.com", "Availability Change", "Hi\n\nPlease note that...."); 
  }
```